# Graphql query to update a table in hasura

Tags: graphql, hasura

I am trying to update a table in hasura. I have written the below query to update a row in `users` table where `id`(primary key) is equal to the passed `id` from the variable. If the `id` matches then update the field `account_id` which is `nullable` and `unique` inside hasura.

```
const query = `mutation updateAccountId($id: String!, $account_id: String) {
  update_users(where: {id: {_eq: $id}}, _set: {account_id: $account_id}){
    affected_rows
  }
}`;

fetch("https://xyz.hasura.app/v1/graphql", {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query,
    variables: {
      id: "P9gc6WanL9YAy7JdD6pEbcfULYt2",
      account_id: "3afc4fds2ds4",
    },
  }),
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(
    response,
  );
});
```

I'm getting the below error after trying a few times. Don't know if this is a graphql syntax error or something related to hasura.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "extensions": {
                "code": "validation-failed",
                "path": "$.selectionSet.update_users"
            },
            "message": "'update_users' has no argument named '_set'"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: GraphQL syntax is fine. Check the parameters of `update_users` - it doesn't look like there's a `_set`. Best to verify your queries in the playground/graphiql before committing them to code.

Comment: I tested the query inside hasura graphiql console now, works fine there. But when I'm trying it from the postman or directly from the code it gives the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The problem was I didn't enable the permission to update the `users` table inside hasura that's why I was getting that error.

Comment: Not a great error message from Hasura there!

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant privileges to the particular role, who is hitting the query. You can do that by going to the Data Tab on the Header, and then going inside the corresponding table. Then select Permission and edit permissions in the Update column.

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvKKx.png)

You will have row and column update permissions there, where you can select without any checks or apply a custom check as per your requirements.

CRUX - In column update permissions make sure to toggle the columns, which you wish to update, or are trying to update through GraphQL query.